# Problems SourceTree listing files in local repository as deleted

Tags: macos, git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

We are two developers working on a large project which involves 30 small satelllite web sites from two differente stations. We have been experiencing problems with SourceTree in the sense that sometimes in the OSX station the area "Work Copy Changes" lists many files as deleted and reques

A. Main issue:

1. Sometimes, before committing or pushing any changes on the repository, on the MAC station SourceTree shows on the working changes area that many files have been deleted. But when we check if the files still exist on the project folder of the MAC, they are still there.
2. We cannot proceed to pull or pushing any more changes until we go file by file ignoring the changes for each file or we make another commit confirming the deletion of the files.
3. This seems to be happening erratically when one of us pushes changes onto the repository.
4. Although we don’t know if it may be related to this, another issue that has been happening as well is that the folders requested to be ignored on the gitignore file are not ignored.

B. Configuration

1. A Samsung laptop running on Windows 7 and a MAC with OSX
2. For managing (pushing, pulling, committing) contents on the repository, we are using the latest versions of SourceTree (1.5.2 for Windows and 1.9 for OSX)
3. We are using the same software for development (PhpStorm)
4. We are using one master repository and branch for managing all the changes on the satellites
5. The configuration of the GIT config files is below:

Windows station:

```
[core]

repositoryformatversion = 0

filemode = false

bare = false

logallrefupdates = true

symlinks = false

ignorecase = true

hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly

[remote "origin"]

url = dlaggit@dev.dreamit.de:lotto-satellites

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]

remote = origin

merge = refs/heads/master
```

OSX station:

```
[core]

repositoryformatversion = 0

filemode = true

bare = false

logallrefupdates = true

ignorecase = true

precomposeunicode = false

[remote "origin"]

url = dlaggit@dev.dreamit.de:lotto-satellites

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]

remote = origin

merge = refs/heads/master
```

C. What we have tried so far

1. Discarding the changes on the files. The problem has arisen again weeks later with different files
2. Reinstalling SourceTree and making the changes below (highlighted) to the git config file on the OSX machine:

   ```
   [core]

   repositoryformatversion = 0

   filemode = false

   bare = false

   logallrefupdates = true

   ignorecase = true

   precomposeunicode = true

   [remote "origin"]

   url = dlaggit@dev.dreamit.de:lotto-satellites

   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

   [branch "master"]

   remote = origin

   merge = refs/heads/master
   ```
3. After trying the solution above, some of the files on the working copy changes area no longer appear as deleted but as modified (even though they had not been modified by us), some of them appear recently added and some remain as deleted. When we check the files in the local folder, the files are still there.

   Thanks for any help you can provide.